# Accessing object properties using Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm new to Flask and templating; I am trying to pass an object and display its data on my HTML pages.

I have a detachment class like

```
class Detachment:
    def __init__(self, name, ...):
        self.name = name
        self.... = ... # lots of data, mostly lists that I'd like to index
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
import Detachment as dt
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for

@app.route('/')
def go():
    # stuff
    testDetachment = dt.Detachment('name')
    return redirect(url_for('cooliofunction', detachment=testDetachment)

@app.route('/templates')
def cooliofunction():
    return render_template('data.html', obj=request.args.get('detachment'))
```

with my data.html attempting:

```
{{obj}} <br />
{{obj.name}} <br />
```

While {{obj}} will display the object address, I can't access the variables set in my detachment - it shows up blank. Am I approaching the whole problem wrong, or is there a simple way to access objects' properties?

*EDIT:* I was using redirect because the creation of testDetachment actually depends on a file upload, but I omitted it to focus on the object properties.

***EDIT2:*** So I had been using the redirect because I was following a file upload tutorial that displayed what had been uploaded, but I don't need to do that. Rendering the template directly, I could access the object's attributes directly. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: That looks right to me, your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: I believe by the time your route gets `obj` it is only a string because of how you're passing it. If you want to pass arbitrary Python objects, use `session` or `g`. Even though `name` is not a valid attribute for a string, Jinja simply ignores this.

Comment: OH, I see what you've got there. `request.args.get` is just going to return a string. you need to instantiate a new object in the cooliofunction route handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `url_for` gets arguments that are not part of the rule it's building, it will append them as the query string by converting the values to strings.  The string representation of an object is its address, not the object itself.  When you retrieve it in the other view, you're retrieving the string representation of the object, not the actual object.

As written, you should just omit the redirect and render the template directly in the `go` view.

If your actual code has a specific reason for that redirect, then you should send a unique identifier for the object, and re-load it in the other view.  For example, if you're using a database, commit the object to the database, pass the id in the url, and load it by id in the other view.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your route gets `obj` it is only a string because of how you're passing it. `redirect(url_for('cooliofunction', detachment=testDetachment)` is likely actually passing `str(testDetachment)` implicitly as a query string.

Even though `name` is not a valid attribute for a string, Jinja simply ignores this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def test():
    obj = "Foo"
    return render_template_string("{{ obj }} {{ obj.name }}", obj=obj)
#Foo
```

If you want to pass arbitrary Python objects, use `session`, or some other form of storage, like a DB, that will persist from one request to the next.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what `url_for` is for. Or redirects, for that matter.

Redirects are either for:

1. When a page doesn't exist or they can't access it
2. You've finished doing something (e.g. logging them in) and now they can carry on their way and you want them to go to a new page.

So typically you'll do something like this:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
     if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['username'] == 'the_user' \
        and request.form['password'] == 'super secret!':
         ... # log the user in here
         return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

Or if you really did need to pass on some information you *could* do it with `url_for` like this:

```
return redirect(url_for('page', extra='values', go='here', and_='will be added', to_the='query string', like='http://foo.bar?extra=values&go=here'))
```

But, don't do that.